# Creable vs. creatable

Tags: lexicon

Apparently, both *creable* and *creatable* are used in English as adjectives.
What, if any, are the differences?

Comment: 'Creatable' is what people would use. 'Creable' is not recognizable to me (if listed in the dictionary must be very rare or obsolete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "creable" in the sense "which can be created" the Oxford English Dictionary has two references from the 17th century and one from the 18th. The word used in modern English is "creatable".

This said, "creable" is a perfectly correct anglification of Latin "creabilis". It is just that it is not in common use.